# Check List for true or false

Tags: java, list, collections, boolean

I'm new to programming and trying to create a method which iterates over a list and returns true or false, to check a pizza is suitable for vegetarians. It is only true if all of the toppings in the list are suitable for vegetarians.

Here is my method:

```
public boolean vegStatus(){

    boolean veg1 = false;

    for(PizzaTopping topping : topList){
        if( (topping.isVeg() == true )) {
            veg1 = true;
        }
        else if(topping.isVeg() == false) {
            veg1 = false;
        }   
    }
    return veg1;
}
```

This method does not work, it produces the wrong answer. How do I change it so it looks at all the toppings in the list, and only returns true if all are suitable vegetarian?

Comment: Just return false the second you find a topping that is not veg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a clean logic for that:

```
public boolean vegStatus(){
    for(PizzaTopping topping : topList) {
        if(!topping.isVeg())
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It checks all `Toppings` and if any of them isn't Veg, it returns `false` right away and don't check the others (don't have to, right?). If it checks all of them and none of them were not Veg, it returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that when a topping is not vegetarian, you do not need to care about the rest toppings, there is nothing which can change the state of the pizza after that. Therefore, there is no need to check for the rest. *return* simply breaks out of all loops. If nothing tainted the pizza with stuff vegetarians do not like, you know it has to be vegetarian.

```
public boolean vegStatus(){

    for(PizzaTopping topping : topList){
        if( !topping.isVeg() ) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean vegStatus(){

    boolean veg1 = false;

    for(PizzaTopping topping : topList){
        if( (topping.isVeg() == true )) {
            veg1 = true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }   
    }
    return veg1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `veg1` variable to true, and inside the loop only change it if you find a topping that is not suitable for vegetarians.

```
public boolean vegStatus(){

    boolean veg1 = true;

    for(PizzaTopping topping : topList){
        if(topping.isVeg() == false) {
            veg1 = false;
        }   
    }
    return veg1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
public boolean vegstatus(){    
    for(PizzaTopping topping : topList){
        if( !topping.isVeg()) {
            return  false; //Failed so anymore he is not a vegetarian 
        }       
    }
    return true;// Never failed above condition so he should be vegetarian. 
}
```

Comment: No need to check whether true is true :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this ....

```
public boolean vegStatus(){

boolean veg1 = true;   // by default its true

for(PizzaTopping topping : topList){
    if(topping.isVeg() == false) {
        veg1 = false; // if any one id  not suitable then its false
    }   
}
return veg1; // at the end returning the result.. 
}
```

If you have any doubts then you can ask again...